# What does the Asp.net Identity task extension WithCurrentCulture() do and why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to understand the inner workings of the Asp.net Identity system and have seen that all of the `async` calls it seems to make use of the `WithCurrentCulture()` task extension. I have looked at the source code for that extension and I cannot figure out what it is doing or why.

From documentation

> Configures an awaiter used to await this Task to avoid marshalling the continuation back to the original context, but preserve the current culture and UI culture.

Can someone please shed some light on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It executes the task continuation with `Thread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentUICulture` set to the same values as they are on the thread where it was called from.

By default, the culture of new threads is set to the Windows system culture. For example, say you are awaiting a task, and you have explicitly set `Thread.CurrentCulture` to a different culture. Now when you await a task with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the code after the `await` might execute on a different thread than the code before the `await`. Since it is a different thread, it may have `CurrentCulture` set back to the system culture.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = someCulture;
await SomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

bool equal = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture == someCulture; // Might be false!
```

If you want to have the culture stay the same after the `await`, use `WithCurrentCulture()`. It does the same thing as `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but also keeps the culture from the original thread.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = someCulture;
await SomeTask().WithCurrentCulture();

bool equal = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture == someCulture; // Will be true
```

Note that if you OMIT `ConfigureAwait(false)` and `WithCurrentCulture()`, the code after the `await` will run on the same thread as before, so you don't have to worry about any of this. `WithCurrentCulture()` only applies in the case where you want to optimize your code by avoiding an extra context switch.

Side note: you can also control the default culture for new threads by setting [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly if you use `WithCurrentCulture` the thread after the await will be a new thread but it will have its culture set to the same culture as the original calling thread?

Comment: This would explain why I was getting an error when using my DI container to create anything with a `PerRequestLifetimeManager` after the call with `WithCurrentCulture()` as the new thread did not have access to the HttpContext.

Comment: Looks like it's removed in .net 5? Is that correct? Any replacement?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it passes the request's culture information from the current thread into the awaitable's thread. Otherwise, the awaitable's thread would run in whatever the default culture is, creating a big headache when you're processing dates, languages, etc.